# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In::__set_state()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

i tried every method to resolve this, like clear cache,composer update/install, but after `php artisan config:cache`, it appears again.

> In config.php line 839:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In::__set_state()

and whole page turns to blank page.
In **bootstrap/cache/config.php** file it shows:

```
'environment' => 
    array (
      'form' => 
      array (
        'rules' => 
        array (
          'app_name' => 'required|string|max:50',
          'environment' => 'required|string|max:50',
          'environment_custom' => 'required_if:environment,other|max:50',
          'app_debug' => 
          array (
            0 => 'required',
            1 => 
            Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In::__set_state(array(
               'rule' => 'in',
               'values' => 
              array (
                0 => 'true',
                1 => 'false',
              ),
            )),
          ),
```

Comment: Please include where you are using those request rules and if it's form request where do you inject this.

Comment: i think its env error, but dnt know where?

Comment: i'm thinking that you need a leading slash, no? `\Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In`

Answer (score 7):

I also got this error because instead of

> "Illuminate\Validation\Rule"

I have put

> "Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule"

Answer (score 7):

This is issue with `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation` package.

Here inside `Rules` folder, we have class named `In` (file `In.php`)

It is missing function `__set_state` .

If you will add following function in this class,

```
static public function __set_state($array = []){
        return 'boolean';
    }
```

The problem will be resolved. Also, it is temporary solution ( **composer install/update command can remove your function**)

Enjoy...

Answer (score 3):

I think you have some config file with validation rules. Verify if you have `config/environment.php` file or verify other configuration files.

I think in one of them you have:

```
Rule::in([true, false]);
```

You shouldn't use this syntax in configuration files because it cannot be cached, instead you should use:

```
'in:1,0'
```

However it seems to be quite strange to keep any validation rules in configuration files.

Comment: i already check that,but not such file and validation in there,  this recently happened when i updated composer.

Comment: @vinodbhandary Start with searching where `required_if:environment,other|max:50` appears in your code

Comment: thanks bro finally i got it its due to a package after removing it working.

Comment: Thanks! This code help me to find a place where is a problem

Answer (score 2):

just delete file config.php

from bootstrap/cache/

and than run

```
command composer dumpautoload
```

than

```
php artisan config:cache
```

it work for me

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Rule::in([true, false]);` with `'in:1,0'` worked for me. I needed to remove all strange references to Rule class inside bootstrap/cache/config.php too.

Answer (score 0):

just delete file

> config.php

from

> bootstrap/cache/

and than run command `composer dumpautoload`

than  `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if your `config/installer.php` file includes a definition for the rule `Rule::in([true, false])` for `app_debug`. If it does, replace it with:

```php
'app_debug' => 'required',
```

This adjustment should resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting .