# Laravel 7, running artisan config cache command crash with error "LogicException: Your configuration files are not serializable."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-artisan

When I try to run php artisan config:cache command it ends with following error:

> LogicException  : Your configuration files are not serializable.
>
> at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:71
> require $configPath;
> } catch (Throwable $e) {
> $this->files->delete($configPath);
>
> ```
>         throw new LogicException('Your configuration files are not serializable.', 0, $e);
>      }
>  
>         $this->info('Configuration cached successfully!');
>    }
> ```
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Error::("Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In::__set_state()")
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webapi\bootstrap\cache\config.php:619
>
> 2   require()
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:67
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Although it does say Configuration cache cleared but doesn't configure it.

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065513/your-configuration-files-are-not-serializable/57029745

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with the config error if you are not sharing anything about it ?

Comment: HI Thanks for checking. I looked at my cache.php and in the end it looks like this:
'prefix' => env(
        'CACHE_PREFIX',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache'
    ),
I'm using Laravel 7.

Comment: The following thread resolved the issue for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909862/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-validation-rules-in-set-state