# Laravel 8 configurations not serialized - permanent soultion

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

When I try to run the following command in laravel 8,

```
php artisan config:cache
```

I'm getting error:

```
  LogicException 

  Your configuration files are not serializable.

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:71 
     67▕             require $configPath;
     68▕         } catch (Throwable $e) {
     69▕             $this->files->delete($configPath);
     70▕ 
  ➜  71▕             throw new LogicException('Your configuration files are not serializable.', 0, $e);
     72▕         }
     73▕ 
     74▕         $this->info('Configuration cached successfully!');
     75▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8\bootstrap\cache\config.php:1083
      Error::("Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In::__set_state()")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigCacheCommand.php:67
      require()
```

On question [Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In::__set_state()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909862/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-validation-rules-in-set-state), Someone has provided a solution by editing the vendor files but it's not a confirmed fix as it will get wiped out once the composer install command reran.

Comment: are you calling a validation rule in your configuration files?

Comment: I haven't added any validations in the configuration files, all are default.

Comment: You have a `$configPath` available in there, you can add `dump($configPath)` after the line 69, so you can see which config file is failing. After that, you can share that config file in her (and remove the `dump`)

Comment: Following is the result of the dump - C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8\bootstrap\cache/config.php @matiaslauriti
Also, I've checked the path and config.php doesn't exist there.

Comment: It is true, it will not exist because the previous line is deleting the file. You may try to comment that line just for debugging purposes, run the command one more time and check the file (then uncomment that line)

Comment: I've checked the files by debugging the post deleted config files and the error was that the validation was being used by a package's published config files which were calling, Rule::in(['true', 'false']), By removing it now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An in-use package was generating a config file which was calling the function `Rule::in(['true', 'false'])`. By Removing the config file and modifying the condition, it is working now.